# Can <sitemapindex> contain <sitemap> that contains another <sitemapindex>?

Tags: sitemap

Can I put a sitemap that contains sitemapindex inside a sitemapindex?

for example :

sitemapindex.xml contains

```
<sitemapindex>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>la.example.com/sitemap.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

sitemap.xml contains

```
    <sitemapindex>
        <sitemap>
            <loc>la.example.com/post1.xml.xml</loc>
            <loc>la.example.com/post2.xml.xml</loc>
            <loc>la.example.com/post3.xml.xml</loc>
        </sitemap>
    </sitemapindex>
```

for example, sitemapindex1 will contain all post, sitemapindex2 will contain all tags, and so on ....